# Track bar changes variable value with If statements but not Select Case

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to using VB & programming in general. I'm currently doing a school assignment, & I want the value of a string variable to change as the value of a track bar is changed, so that when the user clicks a button it will display the 'selected' string. I tried using Select Case because it's messy to have so many If statements, but the code only seems to work with the If statements. When I use Select Case, it seems to lock in the track bar value as 1 even when the value changes.

Here's my code for the Select Case statement:

```
    Select Case trkAns3.Value

        Case trkAns3.Value= 0
            strPart3 = "able"
        Case trkAns3.Value = 1
            strPart3 = "shine"
        Case trkAns3.Value = 2
           strPart3 = "ful"
        Case trkAns3.Value = 3
            strPart3 = "stroy"
        Case trkAns3.Value = 4
            strPart3 = "ence"
        Case trkAns3.Value = 5
            strPart3 = "ter"

    End Select
```

And here's my code for the If statements:

```
    If trkAns3.Value = 0 Then
        lblWord.Text = "able"
    End If

    If trkAns3.Value = 1 Then
        lblWord.Text = "shine"
    End If

    If trkAns3.Value = 2 Then
        lblWord.Text = "ful"
    End If

    If trkAns3.Value = 3 Then
        lblWord.Text = "stroy"
    End If

    If trkAns3.Value = 4 Then
        lblWord.Text = "ence"
    End If

    If trkAns3.Value = 5 Then
        lblWord.Text = "ter"
    End If
```

Could someone please explain?

Comment: Apparently you meant `Case 0` instead of `Case trkAns3.Value= 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your bigger picture looks like, but you could use a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) to associate your TrackBars with an Array of String.  Then you can lookup the values using a common function.  You'd setup the associations and string arrays in the Load() event of the Form.

Here's an example with just one TrackBar loaded:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Lookups As New Dictionary(Of TrackBar, String())

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Lookups.Add(trkAns3, {"able", "shine", "ful", "stroy", "ence", "ter"})
    End Sub

    Private Sub trkAns3_Changed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles trkAns3.Scroll, trkAns3.ValueChanged
        UpdateLabel(trkAns3, Label1)
    End Sub   

    Private Sub UpdateLabel(ByVal tb As TrackBar, ByVal lbl As Label)
        lbl.Text = RetrieveValue(tb)
    End Sub

    Private Function RetrieveValue(ByVal tb As TrackBar) As String
        Dim value As String = ""
        If Lookups.ContainsKey(tb) Then
            Dim values() As String = Lookups(tb)
            If tb.Value >= 0 AndAlso tb.Value < values.Length Then
                value = values(tb.Value)
            End If
        End If
        Return value
    End Function

End Class
```